# How to create dynamic WHERE select without COALESCE

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, where-clause, coalesce

I have found out that my SQL 2008 R2 database is really struggling with COALESCE function if used within search.

CODE:

```
where 
    i.id_categ = COALESCE(@id_categ, i.id_categ )
    and i.id_brand = COALESCE(@id_brand , i.id_brand )
    and i.id_model = COALESCE(@id_model , i.id_model )
    and i.id_type = COALESCE(@id_karoseria, i.id_type )
    and i.id_fuel = COALESCE(@id_palivo, i.id_fuel )
    and (i.year between @year_from and @year_to)
    and (i.price between @price_from and @price_to)
```

DYNAMIC variables:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInzeratSelect]
     @id_categ int = null,
     @id_brand int = null,
     @id_model int = null,
     @id_fuel int = null,
     @id_type int = null,
```

Search should work with or without these variables.

Benchmark:

```
  with COALESCE = Total Execution Time: 3582
  without COALESCE conditions = Total Execution Time: 13
```

You get the difference ...

Is there a nice solution how to ignore COALESCE and create dynamic SQL select with different approch ?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at Gail Shaw's blog post on [Catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tIn your **very specific** case you should replace all your `COALESCE` **search** parameters with the following pattern:

```
 AND ( (@id_brand IS NULL) OR (i.id_brand = @id_brand) )
```

etc

The parameter is evaluated as a literal before execution, so doing it this way makes the condition sargable. 
This is functionally equivalent to your query except you're first checking against the literal value, which can be optimized away if it is, in fact, null.

**EDIT:** Apparently this is the approach recommended in @Joe Stefanelli's link as well. I originally poached it from Erland Sommerskog.

**EDIT2:** And I always forget to mention `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` too.